# How to specify userId in Vue.js - Vue Cookie

Tags: vue.js, cookies, vue-cookies

I am using vue-cookie to set `userId` in cookies. On login I set a `userId` cookie but it does not show it in my data layer until I refresh the page. It does not even show me that the cookie is in my cookies storage.

I am using SPA so if anyone knows a work around kindly suggest as I do not want to refresh my page.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your login API call please do the following,
first, install package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies.
after that when you receive user object from API call you can do the following.

```
   axios.get("{yourEndPoint}",      
          {
              headers:
          {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
          }
          })
          .then(resp => {
           this.$store.commit(auth/setUserID, resp);
          }).
```

Inside your store You can do following

```
    import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';

    //Mutation to set user ID in cookie
    setUserID: function (state, userID) {
    console.log('Storing User ID...');
    VueCookies.set(user_id, userID);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate ??

Comment: Install vue-cookies from npm package and then on login just write this line 
VueCookies.set(user_id, userID); if you are not using store

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it